# No type or protocol named PKPushRegistryDelegate

Tags: ios, push-notification, delegates, swift-protocols, pushkit

I'm adding PushKit notification to my app and have stumbled into the error above.

What I have done:

1. Enabled push notification
2. Enabled remote notification in background mode
3. Added linked framework PushKit.framework

I extended my AppDelegate with PKPushRegistryDelegate and implemented pushRegistry method:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, PKPushRegistryDelegate {
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, forType type: PKPushType) {

}
.
.
.
```

Everything seems ok but when I build I get the error:

```
No type or protocol named PKPushRegistryDelegate
```

I also tried with extension in that case I got a different error:

```
Cannot find protocol declaration for 'PKPushRegistryDelegate'
```

I'm guessing that something is missing but cannot find what. Can anyone help me?

p.s. I'm using xcode 9 and swift 4

Comment: Did you import PushKit in your file ?

Comment: I did. The problem was that import in Bridging-Header.h was missing. It works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imported #import  in Bridging-Header.h and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppDelegate` file, just add import at top like this:

`import PushKit`

No anything required to be added in Bridging-Header.